# How do I set the state that required browser 'window' variable

Tags: javascript, gatsby, netlify

I have decided to reword my question.

I have a component called 'sku' that uses stripe to sets its public key, then within the render I use that stripe access state in pair with graphql to pull data in.

The issue I run in is when running this on netlify or building it, there is no access to the build window variable.

The work around was to wrap the statement in a `if (typeof window !== 'undefined')` condition that would let the build succseed. The problem with this though is you can't wrap a component state with an if statement.

I'm not sure how to get around this...

The component in question:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { graphql, StaticQuery } from 'gatsby'
import SkuCard from './skuCard'

const conatinerStyles = {
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'row',
  flexWrap: 'wrap',
  justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
  padding: '1rem 0 1rem 0',
}

class Skus extends Component {
  // Initialise Stripe.js with your publishable key.
  // You can find your key in the Dashboard:
  // https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
  // state = { stripe : 'test' }
  // componentDidMount() { 
    // if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      state = {
        stripe: window.Stripe('pk_test_IhM5g81HgmeLxC0CHNoisiRg00084h8HyH', {
          betas: ['checkout_beta_4'],
        }),
      // }
    // }
    }

  render() {
    return (  
      <StaticQuery
        query={graphql`
          query SkusForProduct {
            skus: allStripeSku {
              edges {
                node {
                  id
                  currency
                  price
                  attributes {
                    name
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        `}
        render={({ skus }) => (
          <div style={conatinerStyles}>
            {skus.edges.map(({ node: sku }) => (
              <SkuCard key={sku.id} sku={sku} stripe={this.state.stripe} />
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      />
    )
  }
}

export default Skus
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
const stripe = () => {
  let stripe = undefined;
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    stripe = window.Stripe("pk_test_IhM5g81HgmeLxC0CHNoisiRg00084h8HyH", {
      betas: ["checkout_beta_4"]
    });
  }
  return stripe;
};

class Skus extends Component {
  state = {
    stripe: stripe()
  };
  //
  // Rest of your component
  //
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: this is an excellent solution. I didn't even think of doing something as simple as that, in fact I didn't know you could set state with functions ahaha. 

That opens alot of doors I wasn't aware of, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by added `this.setState` within the `componentWillmount()`

I know it causes a re-render, but it's a solution for now until I find something that better to use.